# Media Queries and JS responsive navbar not fonctionnig

Tags: javascript, html, css

Got 2 problems with my index.html page and I will be thankfull to every person who will help me get rid of it. So, first my responsive nav doesn't work even if the js link is correctly written.
And, my media queries does not have any effect, I want to hide the aside for ipad and mobile users. THANK YOU

```js
let toggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
let body = document.querySelector('body');

toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
    body.classList.toggle('body');
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #C6EFE9;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(../img/banner.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 75px;
  height: 350px;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: scroll;
}

aside{
    max-width: 50%;
    float: right;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  font: serif;
}

aside li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
}


.apercus {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    max-width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 50px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(81, 136, 151, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate3d(10%);
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgba(37, 132, 139, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

img {
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


.texte {
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
}

.lien {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
.lien a {
    display: block;

}

@media all and (max-width: 600){
  aside {
    display: none;
  }

  .apercus {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    max-width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 50px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(81, 136, 151, 1);
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translate3d(10%);
    box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgba(37, 132, 139, 0.5);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <title>Page d'accueil</title>   
    <!------------------------------COMPATIBILITIES------------------------------>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!---------------------------------FONTS-------------------------------------->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!---------------------------------------ICONS------------------------------->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2942c11df3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> 
    
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="#" id="logo"><i class="fas fa-pen-alt"></i> Lilaby</a>
            <div class="toggle">
                <i class="fas fa-bars ouvert"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-times ferme"></i>
            </div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Quizs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Outils</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                <li><button class="btn">Connexion</button></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="banner"></div>

    <aside>
      <h2>FAQ</h2>
      <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lilaby c'est quoi ? </a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="#">Comment prendre RDV ?</a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="#">Pourquoi nous ? </a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="#">Actulités</a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="#">Prochains événements</a></li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
        
    <div class="apercus">
        <div class="lien">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="img/article.jpg" alt="Image de l'article 1">
        </div>
        <div class="texte">
            <h2>Un titre</h2>
            <p>Un paragraphe</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="apercus">
        <div class="lien">
        <a href="Mon_site/pageFormulaire.html"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="img/quiz.jpg" alt="Image de l'article 1">
        </div>
        <div class="texte">
            <h2>Un titre</h2>
            <p>Un paragraphe</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="apercus">
        <div class="lien">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="img/outils.jpg" alt="Image de l'article 1">
        </div>
        <div class="texte">
            <h2>Un titre</h2>
            <p>Un paragraphe</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="js/header.js"></script> 
</html>
```

Comment: There is a typo error on your media query, your forgot the 'px'.
Use this instead => @media all and (max-width: 600px){ ... }

Answer (score 0):

- Your forget **px** on `@media all and (max-width: 600)`, `@media all and (max-width: 600`**px`**)
- `<script>` tag place is wrong. 
  Correct Place: 
  `<script src="js/header.js"></script>`
                   `</body>`
  `</html>`

Comment: already corrected, but doesn't fonction, thank you

Comment: I think wrong code is: `let body = document.querySelector('body');` what is this code meaning ? I not see `.body` or `#body` on CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Add px on media query.
You are toggling "body" class in js but you don't have ".body" class in css you're using body tag.

Comment: This is the JS script corrected header is for the container of the nav. The function dons't work on the clic. 

let toggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
let header = document.querySelector('header');

toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
    header.classList.toggle('header');
});


And the header's CSS is in another file.